# Kotlin - Elvis Operator misbehavior

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Faced an interesting case when [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) `?:` misconducts.

Imagine having something like this

`base64ToBmp(str)?.let { <1> } ?: run { <2> }`

and see that on some old phones and emulators `<1>` and `<2>` code was invoked.

- `<1>` was displaying bitmap
- `<2>` was displaying error

This was acting like Bitmap failed to parse.

**Anyone seen such behavior? Is there a logical explanation?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) returns the value of the specified function block.

So the logical explanation is that `<1>` returns `null`. In that case the whole expression `base64ToBmp(str)?.let { <1> }` becomes `null` and the right hand side of the elvis operator (i.e. `run { <2> }`) will be evaluated.

A very simplified way of reproducing it would be:

```
"foo"?.let { print("<1>"); null } ?: print("<2>")
// Prints <1><2>
```

Depending on your actual use case, [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) or [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) (which both return the context object itself) might be suitable (note that for `apply` the object reference is passed as `this` instead of `it`):

```
"foo"?.apply { print("<1>"); null } ?: print("<2>")
// Prints <1>
```

Comment: just a funny thing that `null` wasn't returned in my case. Debugging shows that bmp received and then I'm getting into `run{ }` block

Comment: What is "bmp received" in your code? `base64ToBmp(str)`? That is `!= null` in my snippet as well.

Comment: yea, but you return null at the end of `let`<1> block

Comment: So your `<1>` returned `null` as well. Otherwise `<2>` wouldn't get executed.

Answer (score 2):

@Marvin's answer is correct, if you want to reproduce the scenario you could try this piece of code:

```
fun main() {
    fun someMethod(param: String?) = param

    fun letBlock(param: String): String? {
        println("<1>")
        return null
    }

    someMethod("some param")?.let(::letBlock) ?: run {
        println("<2>")
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
<1>
<2>
```